# What's the solution of Maxwell's equation to the electromagnetic field in circular cylindrical conductors?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

In the image below there are the first steps in a book on power cables to calculate the distribution of current in a conductor due to skin and proximity effect.
I don't understand how the author used Maxwell's equations to arrive in equations (4) and (5).

[image]

Comment: Please type out the text in the image rather than just posting the image. Images are not accessible to all users. You can format the variables and equations using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I will also suggest that you modify your question to ask about an underlying physics concept, rather than for just a derivation of some equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know mathematically what he's doing, but I'm not sure about the physical justification.

First start with

$$\nabla \times (\nabla \times \vec{E}=-\frac{\partial\vec{B}}{\partial t})$$
$$\vec{B}=\mu\vec{H}$$
$$\nabla \times \vec{H}=\vec{J}+\frac{\partial\vec{D}}{\partial t}$$
$$\implies\nabla(\nabla\cdot\vec{E})-\nabla^2\vec{E}=-\mu\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\vec{J}+\frac{\partial\vec{D}}{\partial t}\right)$$

Here he assumes $\vec{J}=\gamma\vec{E}$ by Ohm's Law, $\nabla \cdot \vec{E}=\rho/\epsilon_0=0$ since the net charge is zero in a neutral current carrying wire. He also assumes the second time derivative of $\vec{D}=\epsilon\vec{E}$ is zero. I'm not sure what the physical justification is for that. Perhaps the author expects the frequency to be low and the second deritative is proportonal to the square of the frequency.

Blend that together, you get:

$$\nabla^2\vec{E}-\mu\sigma_c\frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t}=0$$.

Since $\vec{J}$ is only in the positive $z$ direction, we'd expect the components of $\vec{E}$ to be zero except in the z direction and we are justified in dropping the vector notation so long as it is understood $E=E_z$.

By symmetry we expect the field to be independent of $\theta$. I'm pretty sure his second derivative with respect to z is a typo and is supposed to be r which he maintains in the subsequent line. Here its assumed the second derivative of $E$ is zero with respect to E and this simplifies the Laplacian.

Finally, we end up with:

$$\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{d r}\left(r\frac{dE}{dr}\right)-i\omega\mu\sigma_cE=0$$

where $\omega$ is the angular frequency mentioned in the above equation where $\gamma=\sigma_c$ is the conductivity, and so the reciprocal of the resistivity.

The resulting equation can be solved using the Method of Frobenius yielding the result mentioned at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

I had trouble with the maths at first and therefore couldn't find the solution.

After some time I could understand it better. Some observations on your solution that I think that I understand now:
- I think the derivative of the displacement vector ins respect to time is null because the author assumes that there's no induced magnetic field inside the conductor (please correct me if I am wrong);
- I don't think the derivative to z is a typo, but that is equal to 0 because altough the electric field is in the z direction it does not vary with z.

Comment: I think I sorted out the derivative with respect to z. Our electric field only has a z component by Ohm's law, so the divergence of the electric field reduces to the first z derivative of the z component of E. Since there is no net charge, this derivative has to be zero.

Comment: There's  back of the envelope calculation that might be helpful for resistance, but I'm not sure how to bridge the gap. $J=\sigma_cE$. $E=V/L$ and $J=I/A$. Put that together we have $V=I[L/(A\sigma_c)]$ where the term in brackets is the resistance.